# BigQuery: select elements from two arrays based on the same random operation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this:

| array_1 | array_2 |
| --- | --- |
| [1, 2, 3, 4] | [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0] |
| [1, 3, 4] | [1.0, 3.0, 4.0] |
| [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] | [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0] |

What I want to to is do the same sample on both two arrays. For example, I want to randomly select 3 elements from two arrays, it might generate:

| array_1 | array_2 |
| --- | --- |
| [1, 3, 4] | [1.0, 3.0, 4.0] |
| [1, 3, 4] | [1.0, 3.0, 4.0] |
| [2, 4, 5] | [2.0, 4.0, 5.0] |

which they select the same positions of elements from the two arrays.

What can I do this in BigQuery? Thanks for any help.

I was thinking to do `rand()` on the index of the array and then select the arrays based on the random index at the same time, but didn't make it.

Comment: @NickW Thanks for helping me re-formatting the table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT (SELECT AS STRUCT
    ARRAY_AGG(array_1[OFFSET(pos - 1)] ORDER BY pos) AS array_1,
    ARRAY_AGG(array_2[OFFSET(pos - 1)] ORDER BY pos) AS array_2
  FROM UNNEST(nums) pos
  ).*
FROM your_table, 
UNNEST([LEAST(ARRAY_LENGTH(array_1), ARRAY_LENGTH(array_2))]) len,
UNNEST([STRUCT(ARRAY(
    SELECT pos FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,len)) pos
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
  ) AS nums)])
```

if applied to sample data as in your question - output is

[image]